# Overlay background image of div over image that was loaded through js

Tags: html, css

I am trying to overlay an image in a div ontop of another image from the `<img>`. My code right now is:

```
    <div class="something">
        <img class="pp" src="get_pp()" />
        <div class="img1"></div>
    </div>
```

`get_pp()` is a Js function that gives me the img url before the page loads. And my css:

```
#pp {
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px; 
   top: 315px;
   left: 30px;
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
}   

#img1 {
   background-image: url("../images/img_name.png");
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px; 
   top: 315px;
   left: 30px;
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   z-index:300;
}
```

Unfortunately setting the z-index doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You cannot target classes using #. Target them using a .

Comment: You can see what you did wrong here...http://codepen.io/adityadineshsaxena/pen/uhrms

Answer (score 0):

Your error probably has something to do with the fact that you have your elements identified with class names in your HTML, but defined as IDs in your CSS.

Change CSS to:

```
.pp {
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px; 
   top: 315px;
   left: 30px;
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
}   

.img1 {
   background-image: url("../images/img_name.png");
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px; 
   top: 315px;
   left: 30px;
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   z-index:300;
}
```

Try this for starters.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have used class instead of id

so change

```
.pp {
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px; 
   top: 315px;
   left: 30px;
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
}   

.img1 {
   background-image: url("../images/img_name.png");
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px; 
   top: 315px;
   left: 30px;
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   z-index:300;
}
```

Second use image here instead of get_pp() etc.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ashukasama/4jrNy/embedded/result/)

Comment: thanks, but I have to use a javascript method to get the src of the image because I'm taking it from facebook on a static page

Comment: ok... I think issue was clear to you in program i.e. ID vs class issue